# Yii - Retrieve Drop Down Value before form submit.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yii

I have a web page with drop down menus and many other stuff.
I want to retrieve the value of dropdown menu, I know it can be done using $_POST after submission. But I want to retrieve it before submissions and hence using javascript code.

```
document.getElementById().value;
```

I am confused on how to write this code in my form page.

```
echo $form->dropDownlist($model2,'ename',CHtml::listData
(Lists::model()->findAll(),'ename','ename'));
```

How can I call the function to javascript in the form page?

Comment: Please provide us your whole form. Because most of the stuff you just handle with `CHTML::submitButton`. And do you want get it when click on the submit button? And why do you want it? Do you want proof it's value? Maybe there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropdown id Like **YourModelname_ename**

Get the id of your dropdown and use this code

```
var dom = document.getElementById("idofyourdropdown");
var result= dom. options [dom. selectedIndex]. text; //give selected text
```